# Realm Query Android

Tags: android, sqlite, realm

I'm getting started in using Realm in my android project..

everything was going well.. But I was trying to filter data but I couldn't.

I want to make a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (fromId='id1' AND toId='id2') OR (fromId='id2' AND toId='id1');
```

Here's my code :

```
RealmResults<com.intcore.android.tawasol.Message> results =
            realm.where(com.intcore.android.tawasol.Message.class).beginGroup().equalTo("fromId", fromId).equalTo("toId", toId).endGroup().or().
    beginGroup().equalTo("fromId", toId).equalTo("toId", fromId).endGroup().findAllSorted("date", true);
```

but this returns only 1 result.. it should return 2 results.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks fine. Try split the query into result and then sort it.

```
RealmResults<com.intcore.android.tawasol.Message> results;
results = realm.where(com.intcore.android.tawasol.Message.class).
          beginGroup().equalTo("fromId", fromId).equalTo("toId", toId).endGroup()
          .or().
          beginGroup().equalTo("fromId", toId).equalTo("toId", fromId).endGroup()
          .findAll();
results.sort("date") // ascending
results.sort("date", RealmResults.SORT_ORDER_DESCENDING); // descending
```